# Ableton: How do I play a midi instrument, and then record a loop for arrangement view?

Tags: midi, ableton-live

I've got a remix I'm working on, and one of the steps is laying down some bass piano synth sounds.

I have the sound loop I want, it's a progressive sound loopable over 1 bar..

[image]

[image]

However, when I goto arrangement view.. I do not see the sample loop over 1 bar, and the midi just plays constantly over the entire track (which I don't want.  I'm guessing since it's midi and not a clip.. I need to somehow translate that midi piano roll ??  This must have something to do with arming/disarming a track for recording..

[image]

Any insight appreciated,  I want to just have 1 bar and I can pepper that bass loop later in places.. thank you

EDIT:  I'm seeing in the demo video the guy right clicked in arrangement view and selected `insert midi clip`.. however I have no such option.  Do I need to select something?

Answer (score 1):

It's apparently important where you click, shout out Johey

https://forum.ableton.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=193891

> I'm quite new to Live and I just discovered this problem. Sorry for
>   bumping this old thread, but running the latest version of Live I am
>   still affected. Anyone have more ideas?
>
> Edit: Oh, gotcha! I was a little too quick to post, cause I found the
>   reason the second after. To reproduce the problem, make a selection in
>   an empty midi track. Right-click in the selection somewhere in the
>   bottom of this selection. The context menu will not have the insert
>   midi clip option. However, if you right-click just in the top of the
>   selection, then voila!